# How to find inside points of a kite shape geometry

Tags: geometry

I have the following parameters for $x$ and $y$ axis.
$t=(0,2\pi)$, $$x=\cos (t) + 0.65\cdot \cos(2t)-0.65, \quad y=1.5\cdot \sin(t)$$

If we draw this this is what we get "kite-shaped"
[image]

How can I find inside points $(x,y)$ of this shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $(x,y)$ is in the interior of your loop iff
$$\left(x+{26\over45}y^2\right)^2+{4\over9}y^2<1\ .\tag{1}$$
How I arrived at this: Write $x(t)=\cos t-1.3\sin^2 t$. It follows that along your curve you have
$$\bigl(x(t)+1.3\sin^2 t\bigr)^2+{4\over9}y^2(t)=\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t\equiv1\ ,$$
or
$$\left(x(t)+{26\over45}y^2(t)\right)^2+{4\over9}y^2(t)=1\ .$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for "point inside a polygon" test (and you may consider your shape as an infinite-sides polygon) is:

1. Draw a ray starting at the point.
2. Count the number of times that ray crosses the polygon.
3. If that number is odd then the point is inside the polygon. If even or none, it's outside.

You can do the "crossing part" using a vertical line, so $x_{line} = x_{point}$ and solving the given equations.

Then use the number of solutions as the even/odd count.

Comment: I think you need to clarify that you mean you draw a ray starting from the point, not a line.

Comment: I don’t get your test. I assume with cross you mean crossing the boundary. Given a line crossing the polygon, where is the difference for a point on the line in the polygon and a point on the line outside the polygon? Moreover, given a point on the boundary, while the tangent may for example cross the polygon precisely in this point, the normal may cross it twice (think of a circle)?

Comment: @angryavian Yes. Thanks. Corrected now.

Comment: @PrudiiArca The case "point in the boundary" is always a special case. If one of the solutions for a given `x` is the given point itself then the point lies in the boundary

Comment: Okay. Given your edit, I kind of believe this test. I think you mixed up odd and even though. A ray from the center of the circle to the outside crosses the boundary exactly once, hence not an even number of times...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Dam. Yes, you're right. Edited and corrected. THX

Comment: No worries :) I didn’t know of this test yet (and it intuitively works) but I would really like to see a mathematical precise definition of the kind of shape where it works...

Comment: @PrudiiArca it works for any bounded shape. each time the ray crosses the boundary, it either changes from "inside" to "outside" or vice versa. If the shape is bounded, the ray will eventually be always "outside" so you just need to count the number of times it crosses the boundary.

Comment: But what if I take a very odd boundary curve? Think of the topologists sine curve circle thingy. Choosing the wrong ray may lead to infinite intersections, which can be considered both as even or odd. Even if I want to have convex interior, I might choose a sphere with antenna, which has again the possibility of uncountable many intersections (I guess having $\partial K = \overline{K^\circ}$ for the shape $K$ is a nexessary thing to have but I don’t know whether it is sufficient)

Comment: @PrudiiArca Fair point. Perhaps you should ask a new question about what conditions are needed for the ray algorithm to work.